# String Templates are a preview feature in Java 21 - not working with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-21

I've got Eclipse 2023-09 installed. JDK-21 installed. Java 21 support plugin installed. In Eclipse set my project->Properties->Java Compiler->Enable preview features on.

```
public class StringTemplate
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String      name = "Joan";
        String      info = STR."'My name is \{name}.'";
        System.out.println( info );
    }
}
```

I get the error message: Invalid escape sequence '{'.

Comment: P.S. Works from command line compile & run.

Comment: Eclipse 2023-09 has been released before Java 21. The Java 21 support plugin is the beta of what will be in 2023-12. String Templates (JEP 430) are still work in progress: https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/544

Comment: That's what I was beginning to suspect. Thanks for the Github lilnk.

Comment: That GitHub issue has been closed, but Eclipse 2023-12 still gives the same error...

Comment: @RobSpoor Sure, [this was implemented after the 2023-12 release](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/pull/1513). Use a current build to try out this preview feature, but don't use preview features in production.

Comment: in the meantime you can test them out in the java playground https://dev.java/playground/

Answer (score 0):

java: string templates are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
(use --enable-preview to enable string templates)

1st Option:- Use command line to run java file.
javac --enable-preview --source 21 StringTemplates.java
java --enable-preview --source 21 StringTemplates.java

2nd Option:-

1. Download latest version eclipse version which supports Java 21

Right Click on Project -> Properties --> Java Complier --> Enable preview features of Java 21.

[Eclipse Settings screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLcEb.png)

Comment: Doesn't work in Eclipse 2023-12